# pushback stream example in java textbook help. What is going on?

Tags: java

I am reading this example in my java book:

```
// Demonstrate unread().

import java.io.*;

class PushbackInputStreamDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String s = "if (a == 4) a = 0;\n";
        byte buf[] = s.getBytes();
        ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(buf);
        int c;

        try ( PushbackInputStream f = new PushbackInputStream(in) )
        {
            while ((c = f.read()) != -1) {
                switch(c) {
                case '=':
                    if ((c = f.read()) == '=')
                        System.out.print(".eq.");
                    else {
                        System.out.print("<-");
                        f.unread(c);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.print((char) c);
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("I/O Error: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

> Here is the output for this example. Notice that == was replaced by ".eq." and = was replaced by "<-".
>
> if (a .eq. 4) a <- 0;

When it reaches the single `=` sign, it reads it, prints out the `<-` and then unreads the `=` and puts it back on the `pushbackInputStream` right? So when it calls `c = f.read()`, it receives the `=` again right? so why aren't we in an infinite loop of `<-` symbols?

Comment: Why an image of code? Shouldn't you be posting code-formatted text, code we can compile and test? The question is yours, and so this minimal effort should be yours, no?

Comment: Please don't post images,  Take the time to type it in so we can help.

Comment: I think the push back is the `f.unread(c)` method.  Push back -- pushing a character read back into an input stream -- is a common techique for parsing and other character input functions.  C.f. [java.io.PushbackReader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PushbackReader.html)

Comment: But yes, @markspace's explanation looks to be correct -- but still, please improve your question so that the code can be searched by text search and so it can be more helpful for future visitors.

Comment: `When it reaches the single = sign, it reads it, prints out the <- and then unreads the = and puts it back on the pushbackInputStream right?` No, it reads a "=", the *reads the next character* to see if it's just a "=" or if it's a "==".  Then it pushes back the second character read *only if it was a "==".*

Comment: Please comment back to me once you've fixed the question -- thanks

Comment: As an aside: if you are operating on characters, you should consider using a `PushbackReader`. (But I know this isn't your code). InputStreams are to bytes what Readers are to chars.

Answer (score 1):

The while loop contains two possible branches: one when an `=` character is encountered, and one for everything else. For the everything-else scenario the character is simply dumped out to the console, so no infinite loop is created.

For the branch where we encounter an `=` character, it will then read the **next** character (after that `=` character) from the stream. If the next character is a second `=` character then `.eq.` is dumped out to the console, and nothing is pushed back onto the `PushbackInputStream` so the `==` sequence has been fully consumed and when we go around the `while` loop again it finds whatever comes after the `==`. So this scenario causes no infinite loop.

If the next character after the first `=` is **not** a second `=` character then `<-` is dumped out to the console, and then that **second** character is pushed back onto the stream. Execution of the `while` loop then re-reads this character and (seeing as we already know it is not an `=` character) it will be dumped out to the console immediately after the `<-`. So this scenario does not cause an infinite loop.